# checkbox change issue with model value in edge browser

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

In my angular application i have a checkbox input .
The issue is in IE,Edge browser

below is the checkbox code

```
 <label class="i-switch i-switch-lg pull-right">
         <input type="checkbox" name="mytoggle" [(ngModel)]="togglestatus" (click)="checkstatus($event)" />
        <i></i>
```

In my component i have code based on the status of the input
below is the code

```
checkstatus(e){
    console.log(this.togglestatus);

    if (this.togglestatus) 
       console.log("toggle selected");           
    else 
       console.log("toggle not selected");
    }
```

this works fine in Chrome and Firefox browser but in edge and IE it works completely opposite.

In **Chrome** and **Firefox** i get console log for **togglestatus** as **false**
but in **IE** and **edge** i get it as **true**.

How to resolve this

How to write the function that it works for Edge as well.

Please guide!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `change` instead of `click`

```
<label class="i-switch i-switch-lg pull-right">
         <input type="checkbox" name="mytoggle" [(ngModel)]="togglestatus" (change)="checkstatus($event)" />
 </label>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwlqjm?file=src/app/app.component.html)